# robocopy doesn't work as expected mirror folder and subfolder

Tags: powershell

i need to convert hundrets of .doc files on my server to .docx. for that i have a little powershell script which i need to modify a little bit. i want to backup all folders and subfolders which contains the .doc files to a "backup" folder with the original folder structure. after the backup i want to convert the .doc files and copy the .docx files to the "converted" folder with the original folder structure. my robocopy command with /e or /mir doesn't work for me

```
<#folder picker
########################################################>
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory="") {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
    $foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}
$path = Get-Folder


<#backup
########################################################>
$targetDir = "$path\backup" 
Foreach($file in  (Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.Extension -match ".doc"} ))
{   
   $pastePath = $targetDir 
   if(-not (Test-Path $pastePath )) 
   {
        md $pastePath
   }
   $source = $path + $file
   Robocopy.exe $path $pastePath $file /E
}


<#file picker
########################################################>
$word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

$Format = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatXMLDocument

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.doc | ForEach-Object {
    $document = $word_app.Documents.Open($_.FullName)
    $docx_filename = "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.BaseName).docx"
    $document.SaveAs([ref] $docx_filename, [ref]$Format)
    $document.Close()
}
$word_app.Quit()


<#move files
########################################################>
$targetDir = "$path\converted" 
Foreach($file in  (Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.Extension -match ".docx"} ))
{   
   $pastePath = $targetDir 
   if(-not (Test-Path $pastePath )) 
   {
        md $pastePath
   }
   $source = $path + $file
   Robocopy.exe $path $pastePath $file /MIR  
}
```

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific than *"doesn't work"*?

Comment: with robocopy /e it just copyies nothing

Comment: I'd question why you'd need to scan for `.doc` files by powershell and not simply leave all that to robocopy. Running robocopy inside that loop kind of defeats the whole purpose of robocopy in your scenario.